# OpenIddict using resource server 401 Error: Requires an authenticated User

Tags: openiddict

I'm passing a token with the authorization: bearer {token} header.

The {token} was just issued by the OpenIddict server which is using DataProtection() to create reference tokens.

The resource server is setup like this:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddValidation(options => {
                options.SetIssuer(authenticationSettings.Issuer);
                options.AddAudiences(resourceServerSettings.Name);

                options.AddEventHandler<ValidateTokenContext>(builder => builder.UseScopedHandler<ValidateAccessTokenHandler>());

                var encryptionCert = certificateSettings.IdentityEncryption.GetCertificate();
                var signingCert = certificateSettings.IdentitySigning.GetCertificate();

                options.AddEncryptionCertificate(encryptionCert);
                options.AddEncryptionKey(new X509SecurityKey(signingCert));

                options.UseDataProtection();
                options.UseSystemNetHttp();
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });
```

Which is directly picked up from Zirku sample although I'm not sure if I need to use the encryptioncertificate and key, or if just encryptioncertificate should be enough.  The encryption certificate and encryption key are shared between the main server that issues the token and the resource server and I've verified that they're identical thumbprints. (same with the signingkey)

I'm getting the following in the logs:

```
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+InferIssuerFromHost.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+InferIssuerFromHost.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ResolveServerConfiguration.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ResolveServerConfiguration.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+EvaluateValidatedTokens.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+EvaluateValidatedTokens.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromAuthorizationHeader.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromAuthorizationHeader.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromQueryString.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromQueryString.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateRequiredTokens.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ResolveTokenValidationParameters.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ResolveTokenValidationParameters.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ValidateIdentityModelToken.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ValidateIdentityModelToken.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.DataProtection.OpenIddictValidationDataProtectionHandlers+Protection+ValidateDataProtectionToken.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.DataProtection.OpenIddictValidationDataProtectionHandlers+Protection+ValidateDataProtectionToken.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+NormalizeScopeClaims.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+NormalizeScopeClaims.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+MapInternalClaims.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+MapInternalClaims.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ValidatePrincipal.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ValidatePrincipal.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ValidatePrincipal.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ValidateTokenContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+Protection+ValidatePrincipal.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateAccessToken.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateAccessToken.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateAccessToken.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessAuthenticationContext was marked as rejected by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+ValidateAccessToken.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] info: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler[7]
      OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request.
OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler: Information: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveHostChallengeProperties.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveHostChallengeProperties.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachHostChallengeError.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachHostChallengeError.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+AttachDefaultChallengeError.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+AttachDefaultChallengeError.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachHttpResponseCode`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachHttpResponseCode`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+AttachCustomChallengeParameters.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationHandlers+AttachCustomChallengeParameters.
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachCacheControlHeader`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachCacheControlHeader`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] dbug: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachWwwAuthenticateHeader`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Debug: The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+AttachWwwAuthenticateHeader`1[[OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessChallengeContext, OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f]].
[2022-11-29 16:16:41] info: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
      The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
        "error": "invalid_token",
        "error_description": "The specified token is invalid.",
        "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2004"
      }.
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Information: The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "The specified token is invalid.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2004"
}.
```

I can't find anything in there that tells me why it failed or even how to intercept what's throwing it so that I can get any more information and this is with logging set to trace.

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?